# I don't understand how image_datagen.flow_from_dataframe works

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to perform a classification algorithm under Tensorflow.
I have created a dataframe with the file path of the files and the associated class.

When I do the train generator:

```
train_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df_train,
    x_col="files",
    y_col="class",
    target_size=(256, 256),
    batch_size=4,
    color_mode="rgb",
    class_mode="sparse")

valid_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
   df_valid,
   x_col="files",
   y_col="class",
   target_size=(256, 256),
   batch_size=4,
   color_mode="rgb",
  class_mode="sparse")
```

I have the following error message:

```
C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py:1137: UserWarning: Found 19856 invalid image filename(s) in x_col="files". These filename(s) will be ignored.
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py:1137: UserWarning: Found 2206 invalid image filename(s) in x_col="files". These filename(s) will be ignored.
  warnings.warn(
```

I don't understand if it comes from the function itself or my method.
Indeed the file path of my dataset is already "object" but I have to pass them as a string if I don't won't error message because I chose class_mode="sparse":

```
df_train["files"] = df_train["files"].astype(str)
df_train["class"] = df_train["class"].astype(str)

df_valid["files"] = df_valid["files"].astype("str")
df_valid["class"] = df_valid["class"].astype(str)
```

But if I look at the path it becomes, for example:

`'F:\\DATA_SCIENCE\\DATA_MAMOGRAPHY\\TRAIN_IMAGES\\16432\\484722668.dcm'`

The \ \ seems to me strange.
Does the issue comes from here?
Why doesn't it find the images?

Attached is an extract of my dataset.

Thanks for your help.

To change the way I extract the path of the files (walk or glob)

Answer (score 0):

ImageDataGenerator does not support all image formats, in particular .dcm files are not supported. that is why you get a message saying those images will be ignored.

From the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/):

> Supported image formats: jpeg, png, bmp, gif. Animated gifs are truncated to the first frame.

Comment: Thanks for your support but I use flow from dataframe and no flow from directory

Comment: @jthibaut it has the same limitations.

Comment: Thank you ! I should have asked sooner ! It would have avoided me to loose my time !